# How to get started with NodeJS and Sass project, so I can customize bootstrap 4 theme

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to customize Bootstrap 4 theme such as colors, fonts, etc..

I read the instructions from Bootstrap website saying that I need to create custom.scss file and import Bootstrap’s source Sass files like this

```
// Custom.scss

// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I'm new to both Sass and NodeJS and I do not know how to get started with a NodeJS and Sass project.

I went as far as installing NodeJS and Sass on my Mac using brew. I also installed Bootstrap by typing:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

This is the most progress I have made. I do not know in which path the bootstrap files are installed when I did the command npm install bootstrap and also I do not know how to bring that Bootstrap installation into my project folder.

Could anyone please provide some information or point me to a resource on how to get started with a NodeJS and Sass project so I can customize  Bootstrap 4 theme using Sass.

Comment: Hi just to confirm, what do you have right now and what are you trying to do? Node is used for npm which is used to install Bootstrap, but I imagine you have to edit a specific Bootstrap file for your project.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like customizing the default Bootstrap 4 theme requires Sass. I just need information on how to manage a website with Sass in my Mac. I have installed NodeJS, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I think what you want to happen is that you need a way to get the Bootstrap Sass files, use the Sass compiler which then compiles it to CSS, which you can then plop them onto the site. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `npm install bootstrap` command inside your project directory. Bootstrap and its files will then be installed into the directory `node_modules/bootstrap` inside your project directory.

Now, when placing your custom scss files into this folder, they will be able to access the `node_modules` directory, in which bootstrap is.

You can then create a custom building pipeline using npm tools for compiling scss files to css. This requires more in-depth knowledge on node.js and NPM, but that is the usual and recommended way of doing it.

If you just want to compile the scss once and work with the css from there without having to use node.js more in depth, you can use packages like [scss-compile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-compile) and then use console commands like `node-sass -rw scssFiles -o cssOutputFiles` to compile your custom theme once.